# How can I construct such set?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it possible to construct a uncountable set $S\subset (0,1]$ which satisfies:

$I_0$ - Every sequence $(x_{n})\subset S$ has the property $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_{n}<\infty$

$I_1$ - Take any sequence of disjoint sequences in $S$, i.e. if $x_{k,n}$ are sequences in $S$ (for fixed $k$), then $x_{k,n}\neq x_{s,m}$ for all $n,m,s,k$. If we enumarate the sum of the sequences, i.e. $x_{1,k}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_{k,n}$ then $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty} x_{1,k}<\infty$

Is it possible to construct a uncountable set $R\subset (0,1]$ which satisfies: $I_0$, $I_1$ and :

$I_2$ - We repeat the process in $I_1$, but now with the sequences of sums formed in $I_1$.

...

$I_{n+1}$ - We repeat the process $I_1$, but now with the sequences of sums formed in $I_n$.

...

I tried to make things all clear, but it is really hard to write what I am thinking. Also I could not find a better title, so feel free to change it to a better one.

Thank you

Comment: Any uncountable subset of $S$ must have a non-zero limit point (see Theorem 4 [here](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2010/05/29/the-lindelof-property-of-the-real-line/) e.g.). So, you can't even get $I_0$.

Comment: @DavidMitra, your answer is what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no uncountable set satisfying $I_0$.

Let $S$ be some set satisfying $I_0$, then for every $\varepsilon>0$ there are only finitely many $x\in S\cap \left(\varepsilon,\infty\right)$. If there were infinitely many I could choose a countable sequence $x_i>\varepsilon$ and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i = \infty$.

Therefore I may arrange the elements of $S\cap \left(\varepsilon,\infty\right)$ in decreasing order, and letting $\varepsilon\to 0$ this gives me a bijection between $S$ and $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let $x\in S\subseteq(0,1]$, then the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x$ cannot converge. Hence we need to restrict $I_0$ to the requirement that any injective sequence $x_n$ has a convergent sum.

Now note the following:
$$S = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty S\cap\left(\frac{1}{n},1\right]$$
since this is a countable union and since $S$ is uncountable, there needs to be an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $S\cap\left(\frac{1}{n},1\right]$ is uncountable.
But then there is an injective sequence $(x_m)\subseteq S\cap\left(\frac{1}{n},1\right]\subseteq S$ and clearly $\sum_{m=1}^\infty x_m < \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = \infty$.
Thus even for injective sequences $I_0$ can never be satisfied.